# How to extract file data from an HTTP MIME-encoded message in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

I have a program that accepts HTTP post of files and write all the POST result into a file, I want to write a script to delete the HTTP headers, only leave the binary file data, how to do it?

The file content is below (the data between `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` and `------------KM7cH2GI3cH2Ef1Ij5gL6GI3Ij5GI3` is what I want:

```
POST /?user_name=vvvvvvvv&size=837&file_name=logo.gif& HTTP/1.1^M
Accept: text/*^M
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------KM7cH2GI3cH2Ef1Ij5gL6GI3Ij5GI3^M
User-Agent: Shockwave Flash^M
Host: 192.168.0.198:9998^M
Content-Length: 1251^M
Connection: Keep-Alive^M
Cache-Control: no-cache^M
Cookie: cb_fullname=ddddddd; cb_user_name=cdc^M
^M
------------KM7cH2GI3cH2Ef1Ij5gL6GI3Ij5GI3^M
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Filename"^M
^M
logo.gif^M
------------KM7cH2GI3cH2Ef1Ij5gL6GI3Ij5GI3^M
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Filedata"; filename="logo.gif"^M
Content-Type: application/octet-stream^M
^M
GIF89an^@I^^M
------------KM7cH2GI3cH2Ef1Ij5gL6GI3Ij5GI3^M
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Upload"^M
^M
Submit Query^M
------------KM7cH2GI3cH2Ef1Ij5gL6GI3Ij5GI3-
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do this as the file is going over, or is this something you want to do after the file comes over?

Almost any scripting language should work. My AWK is a bit rusty, but...

```
awk '/^Content-Type: application\/octet-stream/,/^--------/'
```

That should print everything between `application/octet-stream` and the `----------` lines. It might also include both those lines too which means you'll have to do something a bit more complex:

```
BEGIN {state = 0}
{
    if ($0 ~ /^------------/) {
        state = 0;
    }
    if (state == 1) {
        print $0
    }
    if ($0 ~ /^Content-Type: application\/octet-stream/) {
        state = 1;
    }
}
```

The `application\/octet-stream` line is after the print statement because you want to set `state` to `1` after you see `application/octet-stream`.

Of course, being Unix, you could pipe the output of your program through awk and then save the file.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Python, [`email.parser.Parser`](http://docs.python.org/library/email.parser.html#parser-class-api) will allow you to parse a multipart MIME document.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a crazy idea, but I would try stripping the headers with procmail.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [Mime::Tools suite](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MIME%3a%3aTools) for Perl. It has a rich set of classes; I’m sure you could put something together in just a few lines.

Answer (score 0):

This probably contains some typos or something, but bear with me anyway. First determine the boundary (`input` is the file containing the data - pipe if necessary):

```
boundary=`grep '^Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=' input|sed 's/.*boundary=//'`
```

Then filter the `Filedata` part:

```
fd='Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Filedata"'
sed -n "/$fd/,/$boundary/p"
```

The last part is filter a few extra lines - header lines before and including the empty line and the boundary itself, so change the last line from previous to:

```
sed -n "/$fd/,/$boundary/p" | sed '1,/^$/d' | sed '$d'
```

- `sed -n "/$fd/,/$boundary/p"` filters the lines between the `Filedata` header and the boundary (inclusive),
- `sed '1,/^$/d'` is deleting everything up to and including the first line (so removes the headers) and
- `sed '$d'` removes the last line (the boundary).

After this, you wait for Dennis (see comments) to optimize it and you get this:

```
sed "1,/$fd/d;/^$/d;/$boundary/,$d"
```

Now that you've come here, scratch all this and do what Ignacio suggested. Reason - this probably won't work (reliably) for this, as GIF is binary data.

Ah, it was a good exercise! Anyway, for the lovers of `sed`, here's the excellent page:

- http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt

Outstanding information.

Comment: No need to call `sed` three times at the end: `sed "1,/$fd/d;/$boundary/,$d"`

Comment: @Dennis Sweet - just needs another one (to delete extra headers after Filedata header): `sed "1,/$fd/d;/^$/d;/$boundary/,$d"`. I'll edit to add.